# confused on a part of the Lua, Reference manual Lexical Conventions

Tags: lua, reference, manual

Im simply wondering what the lua reference 5.4 reference manual meant by

The following strings denote other tokens:

```
 +     -     *     /     %     ^     #
 &     ~     |     <<    >>    //
 ==    ~=    <=    >=    <     >     =
 (     )     {     }     [     ]     ::
 ;     :     ,     .     ..    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These tokens are special keywords as well. Before this quote Lua Manual talks about variables and reserved keywords. Since these tokens doesn't contain letters, they are not listed in reserved keywords, so it calls them "other tokens"